# Problem with getting last inserted ID from database - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, transactions

I am trying to add data to the User table (after registration). Immediately after user data is added to the user table I wan't to create row with userID in 'profile' table (1:1) and that's why I use transactions here. But the problem is I can't get UserId of the user after insert (@@Identity) when code comes to 'ExecuteScalar()' line exception that I receive is `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

```
    string sqlAddUser = string.Format("insert into tbl_users ([UserName],[Email],[Password],[PasswordSalt],[CreatedDate],[IsActivated],[IsLockedOut],[LastLoginDate],[LastLockedOutDate], [NewEmailKey]) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}', '{9}')",
        user.UserName, user.Email, user.Password, user.PasswordSalt, user.CreatedDate, user.IsActivated, user.IsLockedOut, user.LastLockedOutDate, user.LastLoginDate, user.NewEmailKey);

    SqlCommand cmdAddUser = new SqlCommand(sqlAddUser, conn, transaction);
    int result = cmdAddUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand cmdGetLastIdentity = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", conn, transaction);                        
    int i = (int)cmdGetLastIdentity.ExecuteScalar();

    string sqlAddUserProfile = string.Format("insert into tbl_profile (UserId) values ({0})", i);
    SqlCommand cmdAddUserProfile = new SqlCommand(sqlAddUserProfile, conn, transaction);

    cmdAddUserProfile.ExecuteNonQuery();

    transaction.Commit();

    return GetUser(username);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    transaction.Rollback();
}
```

Comment: Don't use a separate query to get `@@IDENTITY`. Return `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in your original query.

Comment: So I can return identity from 'sqlAddUser' query. Can you provide some exaple code?

Comment: I've just noticed you are building your query using concatenation. You should stop this immediately and use parameterised queries or your web site will extremely likely get hacked via SQL injection. You would then add `;SELECT @newid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to the end of your parameterised query and pass in an output parameter of that name. Sorry can't be bothered to give sample code hence comments not answer. Hopefully someone else will!

Comment: For now I just build queries to work later I will add parameters. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in a single statement by using the [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause with INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE statements.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (...) OUTPUT inserted.Id VALUES (...)";
var id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

You can output any database-generated values, and read the values using SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() which will execute the insert and output inserted values as a table.

Note: Don't use string formating, use sql parameters, otherwise you are vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 3):

One of the comments was spot on -- construct your inserts like this and you're asking for SQL injection. Here's what you should probably do:

```
var cmdAddUser = new SqlCommand(@"insert into tbl_users (
                                      [UserName],
                                      [Email],
                                      [Password],
                                      [PasswordSalt],
                                      [CreatedDate],
                                      [IsActivated],
                                      [IsLockedOut],
                                      [LastLoginDate],
                                      [LastLockedOutDate], 
                                      [NewEmailKey]) 
                                  values (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p4, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10); 
                                  select SCOPE_IDENTITY();", conn, transaction);

cmdAddUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", user.UserName);
cmdAddUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", user.Email);
cmdAddUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", user.Password);
cmdAddUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", user.PasswordSalt);
cmdAddUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", user.CreateDate);
cmdAddUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", user.IsActivated);
cmdAddUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", user.IsLockedOut);
cmdAddUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", user.LastLoginDate);
cmdAddUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", user.LastLockedOutDate);
cmdAddUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", user.NewEmailKey);

var newId = (int)cmdAddUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Then proceed with your profile operations using the result
```

You might already be doing this, but I'd wrap your operations in a `using` statement so you properly dispose of your database objects.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a stored proc on the server that will insert the new user and return it's id.

Comment: The OP doesn't need to create a stored proc at all. parameterised adhoc SQL can use output parameters or they could just ExecuteScalar. The stored proc issue is completely irrelevant.